# c++11 threading vs .Net threading?

Tags: c++, .net, multithreading

Which one should I use in my **C++11/CLI program**?

Which is the pros and which is the cons of c++11 threading and .net threading?

Comment: C++ .NET?  Do you mean C++/CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My program is windows only and is built with .net.

Considering that managed languages usually prefer developer productivity over performance (when in conflict), I'd say that managed threading is likely to be more developer friendly. Also, Garbage Collection is a well-known productivity feature.

Do you have an extreme need for performance and/or control? If not, I recommend managed code and managed threading.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 would be a standard based, platform independent way of going about threading. This is important if you need to work across platforms.

Threading with .Net will typically tie your application with the OS (Windows). This has some advantages such as garbage collection (which is amiss in standard C++). However, note that you will probably need to ship the .Net framework with your application. Issues across versions of the framework are not too uncommon.

Comment: My program is windows only and is built with .net. I'm now thinking of implement threading in the program and I'm wondering which one to choose. I'm programing with visual studio 2012 RC so it has c++11...

Comment: I couldn't find a reference for VS2012RC but do check a) if you need *Thread Local Storage* and b) if you do, if it is supported. (They had partical TLS support for vc11.) The .NET threading library does however support TLS. My suggestion would be to jot down *exactly* what support you require from your threading library and check if C++11 on VS2012 support covers it or not. The advantage of using C++11 Threads is that they play nice with the other standard libraries/containers.

Comment: Considering this is a C++/CLI question I think it's safe to assume that cross-platform functionality is not important.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about managed vs. native, then use managed code C# as much as possible, it's a much nicer developer experience all around.  Also, the .NET 4 supports excellent APIs to help with multithreading, see Task Parallel Library (TPL) and the concurrent collections support, for starters.

The general purpose advice is to use managed code as much as possible, then use interop to native only as needed, for problems that don't quite fit the managed solution.

If you are asking about using C# vs. C++/CLI, then use C#.  Both are CLI (managed) languages, but C++/CLI is more difficult to work with and is best used for some managed/native boundary scenarios.  Also, C++/CLI doesn't support Intellisense (at least for VS2010, maybe now supported in 2012?)

Answer (score 0):

Consider tenure: .NET threading has been around for a long time and is known to work with C++/CLI.  C++11 threading is new, and I could totally see problems arising between that and C++/CLI since the /CLI stuff isn't as mainstream and it's likely that few other people are using /CLI and C++11 threading together.